# Software for cryptography (e.g. RSA encryption)

Tags: windows, osx, encryption

I am relatively new to the topic cryptograpy. I am asked to find a valid encryption and a valid decryption key for RSA, given some large prime pumbers $p$ and $q$.

I know how to do this when $p$ and $q$ are small primes, but in this case its hard for me to find phi($p*q$) and also the inverse.

I am just wondering if there is some good software I can use for this and some other similar problems. As for operating systems: I would prefer software that runs on MacOS, but Windows is also fine.

Comment: Your question is off topic here, but Cryptool is a powerful and simple program in cryptography. This program support hash functions, symmetric, asymmetric, protocols steganography and other fields of cryptography.